# remove outliers from geom_split_violin

Tags: r, ggplot2, outliers, violin-plot

Hi there I recently got the desired output for a `geom_split_violin`; however, I do wish to have a much cleaner plot getting rid of all potential outliers which happens to connect the two aspects I'm comparing. *See* below for plot:
[image]

and code:

```
library(dplyr)
library(readxl)
library(tibble)
library(ggplot2)
library(hrbrthemes)
library(introdataviz)

### IMPORT THE DATASET
variants_dist <- read_excel("path/to/file.xlsm", 10)


### FEATURES WRANGLING TO GET THE RIGHT FORMAT
variants_dist <- variants_dist %>%
  mutate(population_ID=factor(population_ID, levels=c("AFR", "EUR", "MENA", "SAS", "CEA", "SIB", "OCE", "AME")))
variants_dist %>% arrange(population_ID) -> pop_sort

pop_sort <- pop_sort %>%
  mutate(variant_type=factor(variant_type, levels=c("SNPs", "INDELs")))
pop_sort %>% arrange(variant_type) -> variant_sort


df_var = variant_sort %>% group_by(population_ID) %>% summarise(num=n())


### PLOT THE DATA
violin_variants <- variant_sort %>%
  left_join(df_var) %>%
  mutate(pop_count = paste0(population_ID, "\n", "n=", num/2)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=forcats::fct_inorder(pop_count), y=count, fill=population_ID, alpha=variant_type)) +
  geom_split_violin(position="identity", trim=FALSE) +
  scale_fill_manual(values=c(EUR="dodgerblue2", MENA="mediumvioletred", SIB="darkkhaki", 
                             CEA="firebrick2", AFR="olivedrab2", OCE="powderblue", 
                             SAS="darksalmon", AME="plum2")) +
  scale_alpha_manual(values=c("SNPs"=1, "INDELs"=.25)) +
  theme_bw() + theme(legend.title=element_text(face='italic'), legend.position='bottom') +
  guides(
    fill="none",
    alpha=guide_legend(override.aes=list(fill=c("black","black")), title="variant type", 
                       title.position="top", title.hjust=.5)
  ) +
  xlab("") + ylab("")

violin_variants
```

If helpful I also share the `dput()` for the first 36 samples, although I'm not sure whether any of them fall in the "outlier" category. Small toy dataset:

```
structure(list(samples = c("abh100 - number of:", "abh107 - number of:", "ALB212 - number of:", "Ale14 - number of:", "Ale20 - number of:", "Ale22 - number of:", "Ale32 - number of:", "altai363p - number of:", "armenia293 - number of:", "Armenian222 - number of:", "AV-21 - number of:", "Ayodo_430C - number of:", "Ayodo_502C - number of:", "Ayodo_81S - number of:", "B11 - number of:", "B17 - number of:", "Bishkek28439 - number of:", "Bishkek28440 - number of:", "Bu16 - number of:", "Bu5 - number of:", "BulgarianB4 - number of:", "BulgarianC1 - number of:", "ch113 - number of:", "CHI-007 - number of:", "CHI-034 - number of:", "DNK05 - number of:", "DNK07 - number of:", "DNK11 - number of:", "Dus16 - number of:", "Dus22 - number of:", "Esk29 - number of:", "Est375 - number of:", "Est400 - number of:", "HG00126 - number of:", "HG00128 - number of:"), population_ID = c("MENA", "MENA", "EUR", "SIB", "SIB", "SIB", "SIB", "SIB", "EUR", "EUR", "EUR", "AFR", "AFR", "AFR", "SAS", "SAS", "SIB", "SIB", "CEA", "CEA", "EUR", "EUR", "EUR", "CEA", "CEA", "AFR", "AFR", "AFR", "OCE", "OCE", "SIB", "EUR", "EUR", "EUR", "EUR"), snps = c(4847876, 4820146, 4875942, 4848405, 4846958, 4893150, 4886498, 4778500, 4868602, 4861225, 5513106, 5726596, 5766508, 5372587, 4974419, 4894272, 4870208, 4913870, 4923787, 4925207, 4840414, 4798908, 4891562, 4953420, 4881495, 5605004, 5703805, 5643221, 4831148, 4829405, 4688483, 4783761, 4778239, 4774887, 4811481)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -35L))
```

**EDIT** for @Seth
[image]

Comment: Hi Matteo. If you create facets with the `variant_type` variable (e.g. `facet_wrap(~variant_type, ncol = 1)`), you can be sure to keep the two groups separate. This may also let you remove the legend in your current example.

Comment: @Seth, great advice I already explored that option (*see* the edit in the message above); however, for some reason, I always liked the idea of having two side-by-side violin plots with different type of information. In fact, the standard symmetrical view of the same data does not optimize plot space and visual but, ultimately, I will go for the most reasonable option I guess. Let me know what you think, thanks!

Comment: Sorry if I'm not getting it, but can't you just filter those values? `data |> filter(!(population_ID == "EUR" & count < 4100000 & count > 3900000))`

Comment: @BastiánOleaHerrera I see the concept and in principle the idea should work but, for some reason, once I plot I'm not getting rid of them in the `geom_split_violin`...

Comment: I mean, it *should* work, as you are literally removing the outlier points, therefore they shouldn't be plotted. There must be other stuff going on. Try verifying that you really removed the observations, check if you really saved the filtered data in a new object, and then plot using that new object.